# Split function using space or :

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to get "CHIP3_0.L.1.2" from the below input line by splitting based on space like line.split(" ")[1].strip() ,does anyone have any better inputs?

```
line=ProductLine:    CHIP3_0.L.1.2 OSVer:  HWPlatform: ABC1234
```

Comment: If you already know the string, why do you want to split to get the string ?

Answer (score 6):

Its pretty straightforward -

```
>>> line.split()[1]
'CHIP3_0.L.1.2'
```

To split on the basis of whitespace, just use split() without any argument.

Comment: `line.split(":")[1].strip()` to split it based on ":" and strip away the leading whitespace. Merry xmas.